# J2ME: How to generate random number?

Tags: java, java-me, random, midp, cldc

I just wanted to know how do I generate random number using J2ME CLDC 1.0 MIDP 2.0 ?

Basically I want to generate a 14 digits random number each time when the menu item
Generate is clicked from the mobile's screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with J2ME, however the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/) shows that the Random class is part of the CLDC api, so you can generate a 14 digit number like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    long l = r.nextLong();
    System.out.println(String.format("%015d", l).substring(1, 15));
}
```

Comment: I think this would be less random...Two random long can have the same first 14 characters and not be equals.

Comment: It would only be "less random" if you did the opposite, i.e. try to generate a 14 digit number from a source that has lass than 10^14 possible values. The code above has a different problem: it will result in a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when the random long has less than 14 digits.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I've corrected it to deal with numbers less than 14 digits in length. One other problem with the code I posted was that it would have negative numbers, this has also been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
Random r = new Random();
r.nextInt(bottomX-topX)+topX; //will give you the next random integer in range [bottomX,topX]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Random](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr037/java/util/Random.html) class of MIDP, or the one in [CLDC 1.1](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr139/java/util/Random.html)

You could do [`nextLong`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr037/java/util/Random.html#nextLong()) and then truncate, or use [next(44)](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr037/java/util/Random.html#next(int)) and iterate from there to have a real 14-number long.

Comment: 14 digits will overflow the int variable.

Comment: I removed my code, it was quickly-coded (and non-tested) bullshit...I'll just give him some advice.

Comment: `next(int)` returns an int, the argument can't be larger than 32. That's by the way also what the linked docs tell you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

private static void showRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd){
        Random generator = new Random();
        generator.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if ( aStart > aEnd ) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
        }
        //get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
        long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;
        // compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
        long fraction = (long)(range * generator.nextDouble());
        int randomNumber =  (int)(fraction + aStart);
        System.out.println("Generated : " + randomNumber);
      }
```

you can use this general method for calculating random numbers in any range.

Comment: `nextDouble()` is not accessible in the J2ME version of random

Comment: but i am using cldc 1.0, what for that?